# Сформировать массив

Tags: php

Требуется сформировать массив  из 50 случайных чисел от 1 до 100. Создать на форме поле ввода, куда пользователь вводит число и нажимает проверить. Если число найдено в массиве то указать его индекс. Все что у меня получилось сделать, но мой код продолжает не работать.

```
  <?php

                    $a = $_POST['var_name'];
                   $arr = $i;
                   for($i=0;$i<50;$i++){$mas[]=rand(1,100);}
                   for($i=0;$i<50;$i++){print $mas[$i];print"  ";}
                    echo "<hr/>";

                    function MeDeadInside (){
                         for ($i=0;$i<50;$i++){

                   if ($a=$arr[$i]) {
                    echo $arr;
                    }
                  }
                }


                   if (isset($_POST['var_name'])){
                    MeDeadInside();
                   }

         ?>
  <form method="POST">
    <input type="" name="var_name">
    <input type="submit" value="Найти">
```

Comment: mas и arr - разные вещи вроде? И что нужно сделать, чтобы к массиву добавить новый элемент?

Comment: `$arr = $i;` - откуда $i берется тут?

Comment: Не обращай внимания, код полностью не правильный, уже скинул рабочий

Comment: Если есть рабочий код - зачем задавать вопрос?

Comment: Код я узнал после того, как задал вопрос, и потом, может кому нибудь поможет

Answer (score 1):

Можно также использовать и функцию если она вам была нужна

```
<?php
function MeDeadInside ($var,$mass){
    foreach ($mass as $key=>$value){
        if ($var == $value){
            echo 'Индекс массива - '. $key.' Число - '.$value;
        }
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['check'])){
    $a = $_POST['var'];
    for($i=0;$i<50;$i++){
        $mas[$i]=rand(1, 100);
    }
    MeDeadInside($a, $mas);


}
?>

<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="var">
    <input type="submit" name="check" value="Проверить">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="" name="var_name">
<input type="submit" value="Найти">

<?php
//проверяем получена ли переменная в форме
if (isset($_POST['var_name']))
{
$a = $_POST['var_name'];
echo $a;
//создаем массив и сразу проверяем совпал ли он с введенным числом
$mas = [];
echo "<br> индексы найденные<br>";
for($i=0;$i<50;$i++){
$mas[$i]=rand(1,100);
if ($mas[$i]==$a) {
echo $i."<br>";
};
};
echo "<br> вывод массива <br>";
print_r($mas);
}

?>

</body>

</html>
```